# pie de pagina en fijo pero no al final

Tags: html, css

por alguna razón mi pie de pagina en medio de la pagina y fijo como si estuviera al final ya le di botton:0 y absolute y funciona cuando activo la vista responsive del navegador pero no cuando lo abro en modo normal he intntado varios metodos pero este es el que como minimo en responsive me funciona

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
    body {
  display:flex;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.main {
    margin-top: 7rem;
    padding-top: 1rem;
    padding-bottom:261.19px;
}

.footer {
  bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  color:white;
  background:black;
  
  
  <! -- tambien intente con este 
  .footer_inf {
    align-self: flex-end;
    display: flex;¡-->
```

```html
<body>
</body>
  <main>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum

  </main>
  <footer>
  pie de pagina
  <footer>
```

Comment: ¿El main debe estar separado del borde superior del body?, para poderte publicar mi respuesta necesito que eso quede mas claro

Comment: si esta separado seria asi nav, main, footer

Answer (score 1):

Considero que:

- No requieres trabajar (*para este caso específico*) con un posicionamiento absoluto para los elementos
- Ya que estás trabajando con el módulo de *flexbox* entonces puedes dar un espacio a los elementos entre ellos
- Ese margen superior e inferior que le das al *main* no es necesario, en razón de que separaremos cada una de las secciones pero con *flexbox*
- Ese margen interno que das al *main* no lo considero necesario, en todo caso deja que dicho contenedor tenga mas altura en razón del contenido que va recibiendo
- Con ese código que entregas no veo donde usas la clase `.footer_inf` pero con esta propuesta no parece ser necesaria

Código:

```
    <style>
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      body {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-between;
        height: 100%;
      }
      main {
        background-color: tomato;
      }
      nav {
        border: 1px solid crimson;
      }
      footer {
        background-color: teal;
      }
    </style>
    <body>
      <nav>
        aqui el nav
      </nav>
      <main>
        Hola
        <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas dolores inventore explicabo consequatur tenetur facilis corrupti accusantium, necessitatibus, laudantium harum vel illum! Illo sapiente, aliquam ea sunt et modi, accusamus.</div>
        <div>Sed sapiente consequuntur excepturi nihil deleniti numquam, quod quia ea error animi? Perspiciatis similique quas excepturi consectetur commodi deleniti. Debitis voluptas voluptate explicabo iste dolore necessitatibus dolores, omnis temporibus autem.</div>
        <div>Explicabo eveniet voluptas maiores praesentium incidunt quibusdam, animi distinctio error autem? Culpa eos excepturi ea. Obcaecati corporis similique sed ipsum vel reiciendis est, harum eos dicta ratione possimus tempora porro.</div>
        <div>Iure nam provident reprehenderit voluptate, consequuntur harum similique adipisci obcaecati et deserunt, maiores ipsum velit cumque praesentium eligendi cupiditate mollitia facilis aut ratione veritatis odio commodi natus nihil, possimus accusantium.</div>
      </main>
      <footer>
        algo aqui
      </footer>
    </body>
```

**Referencias**

- [Módulo de flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Conceptos_Basicos_de_Flexbox)

Comment: Podrías poner el código en un snippet BetaM? Creo que sería genial poder ver el resultado directamente aquí, siempre me intrigan las respuestas que usan flexbox

Comment: gracias con space_between se posiciona correctamente, gracias lo de footer_inf es footer solo que lo escribir mal.

Answer (score 0):

No vas mal, si el resto de tu contenido va a estar en `main`, solo modifica un par de css en la etiqueta `body`, debes colocar su margen a `0` ya que al estar al 100% mas el margen del navegador, te desbordará el footer en unos cuantos px.

Con esto no necesitas que tu footer esté posicionado de forma absoluta, ya que estás usando flexbox para posicionarlo.

```css
body {
  margin: 0; /* quita el margen, evita que se desborde el footer */
  min-height: 100vh; /* limita el alto mínimo del body a el alto del viewport */
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
main {
  margin-top: 7rem;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}

footer {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  color:white;
  background:black;
}
```

```html
<body>
</body>
  <main>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum

  </main>
  <footer>
  pie de pagina
  <footer>
```